# iOS - Push Notification SSL Certificate Validity

Tags: ios

Would like to know whether any official apple reference available for the validity period of development and production push SSL certifications.

Thanks a bunch.

Comment: The apple developer center shows you the expiry date for certificates you have.

Comment: Yes. But isn't it mention in somewhere that a particular certificate is valid for this much of period (ex: 3 months)?

Comment: Don't know, but you can always create one and check how much time it gets. Nevertheless, "Apple can revoke digital certificates at any time at its sole discretion."

Comment: http://www.raywenderlich.com/32960/apple-push-notification-services-in-ios-6-tutorial-part-1 says the development certificate is only valid for 3 months. But when I created one a moment back, the expiry date mentioned is one year from now. This is bit confusing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This [tech note from Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2265/_index.html) mentions the one year validity period:

> These certificates are valid for one year but production APNs certificates can be renewed at any time.

I can't find any documentation that specifically mentions how long a *development* certificate lasts. However, I just generated a new one and can confirm that it is valid for **one year**.

Comment: Thanks for the response James. I also did create new one. Yes, that's valid for one year.

Comment: 1 year is just a figurative number for me it expired way before 1 year.